# In org-mode, how to export a clean html

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I am exporting a webpage with a checklist using `org-html-export-to-html`. But in my perspective, the red "TODO" word doesn't make too much sense in the html. Is there a way to export it in a cleaner way?
Thanks

### Update

I just discovered that you don't even need the word TODO in the header to have the checklist working.

Comment: What do you mean by "cleaner"? A TODO in a different color? No TODO at all? Something else?

Comment: just to omit the word "TODO" from the list

Comment: Oh, I see, I don't even need the word TODO to make checklists work (having those `[ ]` that get filled with `C-c C-c`). My bad. I though it was a requirement to put TODO in the header of the checklist.

Comment: That's correct: headlines do *not* have to have TODO keywords. But even if they do (which is sometimes necessary), you can omit them on export. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you have headlines with TODO keywords, if you don't want them exported you can add

```
#+OPTIONS: todo:nil
```

to your file and then export. The corresponding lisp variable (one of many BTW which can be controlled by an OPTIONS line as above) is `org-export-with-todo-keywords` whose doc string states:

> org-export-with-todo-keywords is a variable defined in ‘ox.el’.
>   Its value is t
>
> Documentation:
>   Non-nil means include TODO keywords in export.
>   When nil, remove all these keywords from the export.  This option
>   can also be set with the OPTIONS keyword, e.g.  "todo:nil".
>
> You can customize this variable.